# Gradle project sync failed - Failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3

Tags: android, android-studio

The following error is shown in my android studio:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZDzK.png)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please check this link stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and this stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how to post a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Open your build.gradle file and change this line:

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3'
```

to

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

It should work